# Chrome scroll bar doesn't work on Select drop down element

Tags: google-chrome

I have a select element with about 80 items. When I click the element the select drops down about 300px and shows about 20 of the items, with a scroll bar on the right to scroll down through the rest. No problem yet.  On Firefox, IE, and Safari I can drag this scroll bar down to scroll through the other items, but not on Chrome. On Chrome the only way to scroll down through the items is with the mouse wheel (which also works with FF, Safari, and IE). The bar is present in Chrome, but can't be dragged.

Does anyone know what's going on with Chrome?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue. Please see https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=334522 and https://superuser.com/questions/704736/cant-use-scrollbars-of-dropdowns-html-select-in-chrome-32/704737#704737.

Comment: Seems to be fixed in Version 32.0.1700.102 m